# Code challenge: finding the divisible in a list

Tags: python

I am playing a code challenge. Simply speaking, the problem is:

> Given a list L (max length is of the order of 1000) containing positive integers. 
>   Find the number of "Lucky Triples", which is `L[i]` divides `L[j]`, and `L[j]` divides `L[k]`.

for example, `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` should give the answer `3` because `[1,2,4]`, `[1,2,6]`,`[1,3,6]`

**My attempt:**

1. Sort the list. (let say there are n elements)
2. 3 For loops: `i`, `j`, `k` (`i` from `1` to `n-2`), (`j` from `i+1` to `n-1`), (`k` from `j+1` to n)
3. only if `L[j] % L[i] == 0`, the k `for loop` will be executed

The algorithm seems to give the correct answer. But the challenge said that my code exceeded the time limit. I tried on my computer for the list `[1,2,3,...,2000]`, count = 40888(I guess it is correct). The time is around 5 second.

Is there any faster way to do that?

This is the code I have written in python.

```
def answer(l):
    l.sort()
    cnt = 0
    if len(l) == 2:
        return cnt
    for i in range(len(l)-2):
        for j in range(1,len(l)-1-i):
            if (l[i+j]%l[i] == 0):
                for k in range(1,len(l)-j-i):
                    if (l[i+j+k]%l[i+j] == 0):
                        cnt += 1

    return cnt
```

Comment: Can you add the code you wrote so we can see where to improve it?

Comment: Sure! I have just uploaded it, thanks!

Comment: Oh, sorry for the typo. It should be l.sort(). Thanks.

Comment: @pokfung No comment on my solution? Cannot help without feedback

Answer (score 4):

You can use additional space to help yourself. After you sort the input list you should make a `map/dict` where the key is each element in the list and  value is a list of elements which are divisible by that in the list so you would have something like this 
assume sorted list is `list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` your map would be

```
 1 -> [2,3,4,5,6]
 2-> [4,6]
 3->[6]
 4->[]
 5->[]
 6->[]
```

now for every key in the map you find what it can divide and then you find what that divides, for example you know that

```
1 divides 2 and 2 divides 4 and 6, similarly 1 divides 3 and 3 divides 6
```

the complexity of sorting should be `O(nlogn)` and that of constructing the list should be better than `O(n^2)` (but I am not sure about this part) and then I am not sure about the complexity of when you are actually checking for multiples but I think this should be much much faster than a brute force `O(n^3)`

If someone could help me figure out the time complexity of this I would really appreciate it

**EDIT :**

You can make the `map` creation part faster by incrementing by `X` (and not 1) where `X` is the number in the list you are currently on since it is sorted.

Comment: Ooh this is much nicer. This is just a DFS from here.

Comment: You're still looking at n^2 in the worst case after the sort, since the list might be a whole list of triples (where every number must compare to every other)

Comment: See my answer, particularly the implementation in my edit.

Comment: Thanks a great approach! Let me try it later!

Answer (score 3):

Thank you guys for all your suggestions. They are brilliant. But it seems that I still can't pass the speed test or I cannot handle with duplicated elements.

After discussing with my friend, I have just come up with another solution. It should be O(n^2) and I passed the speed test. Thanks all!!

```
def answer(lst):
    lst.sort()
    count = 0
    if len(lst) == 2:
        return count

    #for each middle element, count the divisors at the front and the multiples at the back. Then multiply them.
    for i, middle in enumerate(lst[1:len(lst)-1], start = 1):
        countfirst = 0
        countthird = 0
        for first in (lst[0:i]):
            if middle % first == 0:
                countfirst += 1
        for third in (lst[i+1:]):
            if third % middle == 0:
                countthird += 1
        count += countfirst*countthird

    return count
```

Comment: There's no need to sort, and the counts can be memoised. [This](https://tio.run/##bVBLDoMgEN17itk0gdYm4LKJJzEuNGKL2tEgxnp6OvhrjH0r3oc3DN1kXy1GzhWqhAz7URnW8EcABIQYGoXEZ1qORQh5TWIiUrgChtthsVsDGjSCyfCpGK4lHh9flOh0F3y2@p/1mOZ8lR5EXVLPxXsxiGN@fR1NgFsM8uTlNZX9LKPsYBD64c0YW@/dQXJahVF0Y6eFOA@Czmi0@0fp3rLFlSFEQkjKOPcF) is an implementation I wrote before seeing your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I guess sorting the list is pretty inefficient. I would rather try to iteratively reduce the number of candidates. You could do that in two steps.

At first filter all numbers that do not have a divisor.

```
from itertools import combinations
candidates = [max(pair) for pair in combinations(l, 2) if max(pair)%min(pair) == 0]
```

After that, count the number of remaining candidates, that do have a divisor.

```
result = sum(max(pair)%min(pair) == 0 for pair in combinations(candidates, 2))
```

Comment: @AdamSmith Sry, right ... I meant sum. I just updated the answer.

Comment: removing primes might not help that much if the list is long enough

Comment: @pyjg The solution is not removing just primes. It keeps all numbers that have a divisor.

Comment: Am I missing something here? You claim that sorting, which is `O(n log n)` is inefficient, then you propose to go through all combinations, which is `O(n^2)`. I get that the number of elements is small, so that the invisible constant term will be of great importance, but even with that in mind, this sounds like the wrong way to go.

Comment: @JohanL Well, you miss the fact that sorting the list is not the aim of this task. You still have to go to through the combinations, so you still have a complexity of `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Sorry for overlooking your comment. I guess sorting is not a big problem. I tried on my computer. It can sort the worst case in the order of milliseconds but the algorithm to count takes roughly the order of seconds (even more with duplicated elements).

Answer (score 2):

Your original code, for reference.

```
def answer(l):
    l.sort()
    cnt = 0
    if len(l) == 2:
        return cnt
    for i in range(len(l)-2):
        for j in range(1,len(l)-1-i):
            if (l[i+j]%l[i] == 0):
                for k in range(1,len(l)-j-i):
                    if (l[i+j+k]%l[i+j] == 0):
                        cnt += 1

    return cnt
```

There are a number of misimplementations here, and with just a few tweaks we can probably get this running much faster. Let's start:

```
def answer(lst):  # I prefer not to use `l` because it looks like `1`
    lst.sort()
    count = 0  # use whole words here. No reason not to.
    if len(lst) == 2:
        return count
    for i, first in enumerate(lst):
        # using `enumerate` here means you can avoid ugly ranges and
        # saves you from a look up on the list afterwards. Not really a
        # performance hit, but definitely looks and feels nicer.
        for j, second in enumerate(lst[i+1:], start=i+1):
            # this is the big savings. You know since you sorted the list that
            # lst[1] can't divide lst[n] if n>1, but your code still starts
            # searching from lst[1] every time! Enumerating over `l[i+1:]`
            # cuts out a lot of unnecessary burden.
            if second % first == 0:
                # see how using enumerate makes that look nicer?
                for third in lst[j+1:]:
                    if third % second == 0:
                        count += 1
    return count
```

I bet that on its own will pass your speed test, but if not, you can check for membership instead. In fact, using a set here is probably a great idea!

```
def answer2(lst):
    s = set(lst)
    limit = max(s)  # we'll never have a valid product higher than this
    multiples = {}  # accumulator for our mapping
    for n in sorted(s):
        max_prod = limit // n  # n * (max_prod+1) > limit
        multiples[n] = [n*k for k in range(2, max_prod+1) if n*k in s]
        # in [1,2,3,4,5,6]:
        # multiples = {1: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        #              2: [4, 6],
        #              3: [6],
        #              4: [],
        #              5: [],
        #              6: []}

    # multiples is now a mapping you can use a Depth- or Breadth-first-search on
    triples = sum(1 for j in multiples
                    for k in multiples.get(j, [])
                    for l in multiples.get(k, []))
    # This basically just looks up each starting value as j, then grabs
    # each valid multiple and assigns it to k, then grabs each valid
    # multiple of k and assigns it to l. For every possible combination there,
    # it adds 1 more to the result of `triples`
    return triples
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! That lets me learn a lot. Sadly, the first one doesn't pass the speed test. For the second one, it runs incredibly fast on my computer! However, the numbers given in the list can repeat. Therefore, using the set function will eliminate them. I am still digesting the second one.

Comment: Oh, I also have some doubts regarding your first solution. I only learnt to use enumerate as " list(enumerate(xx,xx))". What is the difference without list()?

Comment: @pokfung `enumerate` produces an object of class `enumerate` which is an iterable (it defines `__iter__`, so you can loop over it). Lists are also iterable, so this is a Square vs Rectangle analogy (all squares are rects, but not all rects are squares...). `enumerate` objects cannot use list methods (`list.sort`, `list.insert`, `list.remove`, etc) because they're not lists, but you can iterate over them in a `for` loop the same way. Like all generator iterables, they are exhausted once you use them once, but that's all we need here.

Comment: @pokfung try my `answer3` found [here](https://repl.it/JPWc), it should correctly handle duplicate elements at the cost of a little speed.

Comment: Thank you for the information the code, Adam. But it seems that it didn't work well. I tried the case [1,1,1] and I should expect 1 as the output but it turns out to be 0. Let me dig into the details of the code later

Comment: @pokfung this answer expects a lucky triple `(j, k, l)` to be `l % k == 0 and k & j == 0 and j < k < l`. If that isn't true, it breaks the logic of the rest of the function.

Comment: I don't quite understand. But the problem requires me to count [1,1,1] as a valid combination

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you just an idea, the implementation should be up to you:

1. Initialize the global counter to zero.
2. Sort the list, starting with smallest number.
3. Create a list of integers (one entry per number with same index).
4. Iterate through each number (index i), and do the following:
5. Check for dividers at positions 0 to i-1.
6. Store the number of dividers in the list at the position i.
7. Fetch the number of dividers from the list for each divider, and add each number to the global counter.
8. Unless you finished, go to 3rd.
9. Your result should be in the global counter.

Comment: That's what his current code is doing. It's working correctly, just too slowly.

Comment: It is not. The complexity is better than n², not n³.